# JQuery - how to close a parent element from within an iFrame in the parent element?

Tags: jquery, iframe, appendto

couldn't find anything similiar to my problem.

I am writing DIVs by

```
 var dialog = $('<div id="dialog-overlay"></div><div id="dialog-box"></div><div id="dialog-container"></div>').appendTo('body');
```

Within the div "dialog-container" I am creating an iFrame by

```
$("#dialog-container").html('<iframe id="ifrm" class="gs_iframe" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
```

Now the problem is that if I want to remove the element "dialog" from withing the iFrame I only get undefineds. How can I do so please?

I know that I could remove each div by ID but think to would be easier and at least cleaner to just remove the dialog object.

Thank u in advance.

Comment: what have you tried? is the iframe source on the same domain as the parent?

Comment: yes, everything on the same domain. I suppose the reason is because the parent of the iframe isn't dialog but the div id "dialog-container". But I can't figure out how to aim the dialog object the right way.

Answer (score 0):

In the parent page, add this function:

```
function removeIframe() {
    $('#iframe-selector').remove();
}
```

The selector `#iframe-selector` can be anything here

Then in your iframe, just call the function like this:

```
window.parent.removeIframe();
```